# Adding a PDF file path and name to cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add the file path and name of some PDF files into my spreadsheet.

It works for Word documents however when I tried to edit the code to find PDF files it does not like the term ".Filter".

Here is the original Word document code;

```
Sub AddWordTemplate()
Dim WordTempLoc As FileDialog
Dim FirstRow As Long
Set WordTempLoc = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
FirstRow = Sheet9.Range("E99999").End(xlUp).Row + 1 'First Available Row
With WordTempLoc
    .Title = "Select Word file to attach"
    .Filters.Add "Word Type Files", "*.docx,*.doc", 1
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NoSelection
    Sheet9.Range("E" & FirstRow).Value = Dir(.SelectedItems(1)) 'Document Name
    Sheet9.Range("F" & FirstRow).Value = .SelectedItems(1) 'Document Pathway
End With
NoSelection:
End Sub
```

and here is the code for the PDF version;

```
Sub AddPDFCert()
Dim CalCertLoc As FileDialog
Dim FirstRow As Long
Set CalCertLoc = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
FirstRow = Sheet10.Range("E99999").End(xlUp).Row + 1 'First Available Row
With CalCertLoc
    .Title = "Select PDF file to attach"
    .Filter.Add "PDF Files", "(*.pdf), *.pdf", 1
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NoSelection
    Sheet10.Range("E" & FirstRow).Value = Dir(.SelectedItems(1)) 'Document Name
    Sheet10.Range("F" & FirstRow).Value = .SelectedItems(1) 'Document Pathway
End With
NoSelection:
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an `s`, and your filter is off:

```
.Filters.Add "PDF Files", "*.pdf", 1
```